# Excel automation: Get a reasonable file format/extension for saving

Tags: excel, automation, excel-2007, file-format, file-extension

In our Delphi app we automate MS Excel 2007 to generate and save a xls/xlsx file. How should we go about choosing a file format and extension for the generated file?

Hardcoding some values (e.g. `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` and `.xlsx`) doesn't work if the user has an older version of Excel installed. Not specifying a format probably works for older versions too (we're checking this right now) but leaves the question what the correct extension is. E.g. using `.xls` under Excel 2007 results in a XLSX file with wrong extension which leads to complaints when you open it in Excel.

Comment: It should work to save as .xls from 2007. See this link: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm

Answer (score 1):

omit extension AND format:

```
activeworkbook.SaveAs "fred"
```

will save the file as the appropriate type, and supply the extension too. The file will be fred.xlsx in 2007+ and fred.xls in previous versions.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Unfortunately this collides with the current workflow in our app: The user first chooses a filename. Then, based on the extension, we choose a method for the export (CSV, Excel). I guess we can rearrange this a bit. :-)